# ngrx twice reducer call during effect

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-reducers

I am developing using an angular app using ngrx. I have defined the convention below to implement a loading indicator:

- Initially state of each entity is set to null
- Make it an empty object on effect starts
- Fill it with fetched data on effect done

Now one of my effects will be this:

```
  @Effect()
  LoginUser$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoginUser>(EUserActions.LoginUser),
    switchMap((params) => { new LoginUserSuccess(<IUser>{}); return of(params); }), // for loading indicator to be shown
    switchMap((params) => this._userService.loginUser(params.payload)),
    switchMap((currentUser: IUser) => of(new LoginUserSuccess(currentUser)))
  )
```

but the reducer call in the first switchMap does not get occur. What is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem some other way. I now am dispatching another action, inside the primary action to update the state. For example this is how I have done it:

user.service.ts

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(private _store: Store<IAppState>) { }

  loginUser(model): void {
    this._store.dispatch(new AddBusy(EUserActions.LoginUser));
    this._store.dispatch(new LoginUser(model));
  }

  getAllUsers(): void {
    this._store.dispatch(new AddBusy(EUserActions.GetAllUsers));
    this._store.dispatch(new GetAllUsers());
  }
}
```

user.actions.ts

```
export class UserEffects {

  @Effect()
  LoginUser$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoginUser>(EUserActions.LoginUser),
    switchMap((params) => this._userLogic.loginUser(params.payload)),
    switchMap((currentUser: IUser) => { this._store.dispatch(new RemoveBusy(EUserActions.LoginUser)); return of(currentUser); }),
    switchMap((currentUser: IUser) => of(new LoginUserSuccess(currentUser)))
  )

  @Effect()
  getAllUsers$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<GetAllUsers>(EUserActions.GetAllUsers),
    switchMap(() => this._userLogic.getAllUsers()),
    switchMap((users: IUser[]) => { this._store.dispatch(new RemoveBusy(EUserActions.GetAllUsers)); return of(users); }),
    switchMap((users: IUser[]) => of(new GetAllUsersSuccess(users)))
  )

  constructor(
    private _userLogic: UserLogic,
    private _actions$: Actions,
    private _store: Store<IAppState>,
  ) { }
}
```

This solved my problem nice.

Answer (score 0):

An effect is a stream, only the last Action  in the stream will be dispatched.

For your case you can listen on `LoginUser` in your reducer and empty your state.

Comment: Thanks @timdeschryver. Please provide more detail on your solution.